# What is the purpose of UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormControl etc types introduced in Angular 14

Tags: angular

When you run the update schematic to upgrade to Angular v14, it replaces all of your FormGroups, FormControls etc with the Untyped counterparts. However, **if you discard all those changes, there are no errors**, because it defaults the `value` prop of FormGroups and FormControls to `any`. So my question is, why does the schematic make these changes, when the existing types don't break anything?

The schematic log message says the following:

> As of Angular version 14, Forms model classes accept a type parameter, and existing usages must be opted out to preserve backwards-compatibility

However, existing Forms classes are already backwards-compatible. Of the many form groups and controls in my app, when they are left unchanged, there are no typescript errors, and no build errors.

To make my question perfectly clear, why does the schematic introduce all these changes when they are not required?

Comment: Simple because it could. If you were adding controls to the form dynamically, it would break. (It did for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be no other purpose other than to allow you to find untyped forms and replaced them with typed forms. As the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#overview-of-typed-forms) say:

> By removing the Untyped prefixes, you can incrementally enable the types.

Comment: Exactly what is incrementally enabling the types?  Does the author here mean simply that any of the types with 'Untyped' removed, reverts that type to a strongly typed value?  It's obvious :) -- why such a $5.00 word as 'incrementally'

Comment: I mean incrementally because some apps are huge and you can't replace all untyped forms in one shot. Instead you do it incrementally, or a little bit at a time. Also, that's the language from the docs.

Answer (score 2):

> because it defaults the value prop of FormGroups and FormControls to any

Well, It's not true in all cases. It depends on how you define your form group. For instance, if you declare your form group like the below code and then fill it in your constructor, then your form group value type, would be any.

```
public formGroup: FormGroup;

public constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...
  });
}
```

But if you instantiate your form group right after declaration then your form group value would have a specific type and maybe your code would break.

```
public formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ ... });

public constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
```

Comment: l'm still seeing `any` when I instantiate a formGroup in the declaration.

Comment: You can see what I'm trying to say [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-njzbsu?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Line 27 will result in compile error but line 29 is ok.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for that. Still seems like it's backwards compatible though. Nothing breaks, it's just that declaring it a certain way gives you better warnings