# What problem does Angular's Untyped Form Groups solve?

Tags: angular

I see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496394/what-is-the-purpose-of-untypedformbuilder-untypedformcontrol-etc-types-introduc) already and it makes some sense.

Strong typing obviously creates intellisense, prevents various run-time errors by catching mistakes at compile time or preventing them entirely.

I'm really new to this concept of apparently reversing all the benefits of strong typing, forgive my bad sense of humor.

Obviously this Untyped variation solves something.  No matter how much I google something like 'Why Angular Untyped Form Groups' there is no simple English answer.

Here's an unrelated example -- looking over this very complex app we have and extracting from it what I need to write 2 much simpler Angular apps, the term Convention over Configuration came up.  Compare the Wikipedia version to this definition at this [link](https://facilethings.com/blog/en/convention-over-configuration):

"Convention over configuration is a simple concept that is primarily used in programming. It means that the environment in which you work (systems, libraries, language…) assumes many logical situations by default, so if you adapt to them rather than creating your own rules each time, programming becomes an easier and more productive task.

The goal is to decrease the number of decisions the programmer has to make and eliminate the complexity of having to configure all and each of the areas of application development. The immediate result is that you can create many more things in less time."

Bingo! I get it :).

What is the similar easy-English answer to "Why did Untyped Forms, etc. get created in the first place?"

What's the simple answer to "What is the use and purpose of Untyped Form Groups, etc.?"

I get that these are heterogenous.  And that by removing Untyped from any of these one reverts to the strongly typed versions.

Why not code using entirely strongly-typed versions, with some more complexity yes, to account for any need of untyped variants?

Hopefully this is a smart question :)

Comment: The simple answer.... backwards compatibility for older projects. The Angular typed forms were introduced with version 14. When u do an angular update to an old project the forms are renamed into UntypedForm items. In this way your project still compiles and run.

Answer (score 0):

> Why did Untyped Forms, etc. get created in the first place?

Angular introduced typed forms a while ago but before that, forms weren't typed at all and `FormControl.value` was always `any`.

When they pushed out the update, they included a script which migrated all `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, etc... to their untyped versions (e.g. `UntypedFormGroup`).

This was done in order to not break applications when their Angular version is updated.

> What is the use and purpose of Untyped Form Groups, etc.?

I can think of a few scenarios where strongly typed forms could be a problem and/or difficult to implement, but in general you should always use the typed versions, espescially in new code.

Comment: This sentence: "but in general it should be avoided to use the untyped versions, espescially in new code."  means we should avoid untyped forms where possible, right?  Looks like it can also say we would avoid typed forms but I'm sure you don't mean that.

Comment: @user1585204 I edited that sentence to be clearer. You're right though, untyped forms should mostly be remains of migrations when updating to Angular 14 (The update where typed forms were introduced) and should be avoided in favor of typed forms.